# gulpfile.jsでアンダースコアのファイルも出力されてしまう

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

gulpとjade, compassを使ってフロントのビルドをしています。

```
── jade
│   │   ├── _partial
│   │   │   ├── _banners.jade
│   │   │   ├── _breadcrumb.jade
│   │   │   ├── _fixed_header.jade
│   │   │   ├── _footer.jade
│   │   │   ├── _head.jade
│   │   │   ├── _header.jade
│   │   │   ├── _lists.jade
│   │   │   ├── _maps.jade
│   │   │   ├── _recommend.jade
│   │   │   ├── _second_banner.jade
│   │   │   ├── _sidebar.jade
│   │   │   ├── _top_banner.jade
│   │   │   ├── _top_search.jade
│   │   │   └── _tweets.jade
│   │   └── index.jade
```

という構成で`index.html`のみ出力をしたいのですが、`_partial`フォルダも一緒に出力されてしまいます。

以下gulpfile.jsになります。

```
'use strict';
var gulp = require('gulp');
var compass = require('gulp-compass');
var jade = require('gulp-jade');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');

gulp.task('jade', function() {
    gulp.src('./app/jade/**/*.jade')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(jade({
        pretty: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/html'));
});

gulp.task('compass', function() {
    gulp.src('compass', function() {
        gulp.src('.app/sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(compass({
            config_file: 'config.rb',
            comments: false,
            css: './dist/css/',
            sass: './app/sass/'
        }));
    });
});

gulp.task('watch', ['jade','compass'], function() {
    gulp.watch('./app/jade/**/*.jade', ['jade']);
    gulp.watch('./app/sass/**/*.scss', ['compass']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['jade', 'compass']);
```

どなたかご教示いただけると幸いです。
宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2):

`gulp.src`で`!`を使って取得したくないパスを指定します。

```
var gulp = require("gulp");

gulp.task("build", function() {
  gulp.src(["source/**/*", "!source/_**/*", "!source/**/_*"])
    .pipe(gulp.dest("build"));
});
```

上記の状態で`gulp build`を実行すると次のようになります。

```
/
+ node_modules/
+ source/
|   + _partial/
|   |   + _partial.html
|   |   + partial.html
|   |
|   + _index.html
|   + index.html
|
+ build/
|   + index.html
|
+ gulpfile.js
+ package.json
```

Answer (score 2):

`gulp.src`の引数は[glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob)で処理されるので、頭に`_`が付くファイルを一律で処理の対象外としたい場合はシンプルに以下のように書けます。

```
gulp.task('jade', function() {
    gulp.src('./app/jade/**/!(_)*.jade')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(jade({
        pretty: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/html'));
});
```